# Why orientation-preserving self-homeomorphism of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ when $n$ is odd must have fixed points?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

I have the following question:
Suppose the map $g: \mathbb{C}P^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$ is a orientation-preserving homeomorphism when $n$ is odd, then how to prove that $g$ must have fixed points?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to compute the Lefschetz number of $g$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks! So my argument is $L(g) = (d^{n + 1} - 1) / (d - 1)$ which is zero only if $d = -1$, but this contradict to the orientation preservation assumption. Is it correct?